# Split up a string and add each as an item in an array

Tags: c#, unity

I have an input string and input the following "2, 4, 5, 7, 10" (for example). How can I split it as an object(item) for a list array? so it would be in each item "2", "4", "5", "7", "10"

Comment: This question has nothing to do with game development...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string     str     = "2, 4, 5, 7, 10";
string[]   tokens  = str.Split( new string[] {", "}, StringSplitOptions.None );
```

Use String.Split. You give it certain characters to "split" at and it returns the tokens. This isn't Unity specific, nor is it game development.

But there's your answer. Next time try describing your problem to Google. You'll get your answer a lot quicker that way.